# What is the differece between using indexed－column and non－indexed column to update data from different transactions?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, transactional

I got some issue when i was using transaction earlier. Hope someone can help me figure it out. I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

MySql table structure:

```
create table test (
    id int not null,
    someid int,
    name varchar(50),
    update_date datetime
);
primary key : id (auto-inc)
index1 : id (unique)
index2 : id, update_date (non-unique)
```

java method :

```
// consider this method is Transaction 1
method1() {
    A. set session transaction isolation level read commited;
    B. select update_date from test where someid = 1;
    C. insert into test values (some new data..);
    D. select update_date from test where someid = 1;
}

// consider this method is Transaction 2
methodb() {
    E. (start with default transaction isolation level - repeatable read)
    F. update test set udpate_date = now() where someid = 1;
}
```

Here is what i did :

1. execute method1() and break (set break point in eclipse) at D
2. execute method2() concurrent

Note that "someid" is not in the index, but it store same data exactly as "id" does.

Then i got nothing but waiting as long as i don't commit the transaction1 or finally it will end up with transaction time-out. But if i changed where clause to id = 1 of **F**, it will work just fine without any waitting. Here i got confused, because i didn't lock that table or any rows. And if i did, it should not be done, right?

Can anybody tell me why this happed? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition someId=1 requires the database system to scan the full table because there is no index. The insert statement could insert a row with someid=1 and therefore influence the result of the second transaction.

With where id=1 the dbs can determine that only one row is affected by the statment F. The insert statment does not change this row.

I am just wondering, whether the isolation level affect the execution?

Comment: Thank you for you reply! It makes sense about how update effected, at least i think so. Well, i'm not familiar with transactions, but it is little hard to belive that isolation level affects the update statment, to me at least :-)

Comment: btw : it seems like isolation level effects the locking-mode. But in this case i don't see the differences between READ COMMITED and REPEATABLE READ.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on MySQL concurrency control, but I'm guessing you are seeing the effects of locking: until the first transaction commits, the second one cannot know whether the row inserted by the first transaction will even be committed, so must be stalled.

Only after the first transaction finishes can the second transaction continue and either:

- update the row (if the first transaction committed)
- or not update the row (if the first transaction rolled back, so the row was not actually inserted).

The question is: why didn't it happen for the indexed `id` as well? Are you sure you used the same value for both transaction as you did with `someid`? Did you change the `WHERE` clause for both transactions?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, first. My goal is copy some data from "test" as template and insert them back to same table. So i have to make sure i got a right copy, that's why i used the method above for sure. And yes, i'm sure that i used same value for both transactions. Well, i don't know, for now it seems like tkr's answer make some sense here:-). Any other ideas?

Comment: @redfoxlee The fact that second transaction unblocks _exactly_ when the first one is committed is a strong indication there is some sort of locking involved. What storage engine are you using? I found an interesting quote for [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html) engine: _"If there are holes, concurrent inserts are disabled but are enabled again automatically when all holes have been filled with new data."_. Maybe you were just unlucky to hit these holes? Does the behavior you described happen consistently - did you test multiple times?

Comment: Well, i've been unlucky for a while since i got started...But the sure thing is i am lucky on this one, because i'm using InnoDB engine :-). And yes, i did this test multiple times and it happens every time :-(